# Proving that for a linear transformation $T:V\to W$, if $dim(V)=dim(W)$ then $T$ is onto$\iff$ T is one-to-one$\iff rank(T)=dim(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

For linear transformations $T:V\to W$; $V$ and $W$ being vector spaces, I assumed the following lemmas/theoremsto be true for my proof:

(1) $dim(V)=null(T)+rank(T) = dim(N(T))+dim(R(T))$

(2) $T$ is one-to-one $\iff N(T)=\{0\} \iff null(T)=0$

(3) $[W\subset V \land dim(W)=dim(V)] \iff W=V$

---

***Proof:***

Suppose $T:V\to W$ is a linear transformation and that $dim(V)=dim(W)$.

---

Suppose $T$ is onto, then:
$R(T)=W\implies rank(T)=dim(W) \iff rank(T)=dim(V)$

It then follows that: $dim(V)=null(T)+rank(T) \iff null(T)=0 \iff T$ is one-to-one.

---

Suppose $T$ is one-to-one, then: $null(T)=0 \iff dim(V)=0+rank(T)=rank(T)$.

---

Suppose $rank(T)=dim(V)$, then: $dim(V)=dim(W)= rank(T)$. We know: $R(T)\subset W$.

So: $[R(T)\subset W \land dim(W)=rank(T)] \implies W=R(T) \iff T$ is onto.

---

We have found that $T$ is onto$\implies$ T is one-to-one$\implies rank(T)=dim(V) \implies T$ is onto.
Thus: $T$ is onto$\iff$ T is one-to-one$\iff rank(T)=dim(V)$$\tag*{$\Box$}$

---

*Side note:* I was trying to use $dim(V)\geq  dim(W)\geq rank(T)$ for my proof but didn't need to use it in the end. I was wondering whether these inequalities are always true for linear transformations?

Comment: all vector spaces in your problem have finite dimention, right?

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo I believe that's what his third lemma/theorem says, in a sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one unclear part is where you write, "Suppose $rank(T) = dim(V)$, then: $dim(V) = dim(W) = rank(T)$. You don't indicate where that comes from. ***EDIT:** Godel pointed out where this comes from; I forgot you had  assumed $dim(V) = dim(W)$. The proof is good.*

Otherwise, the proof looks good.

As for your last question -- the inequality $\dim(V) \leq \dim(W)$ will not always be true for linear transformations, e.g., you could have a trivial transformation from any vector space to a $0$-dimensional one.

Comment: $dim(V)=dim(W)$ is hypothesis.

Comment: @Gödel Of course!

Comment: @Y.Forman you're right. I think I just messed up the signs and order! I meant: $rank(T) \leq dim(W)\leq dim(V)$.

Comment: @Marc $\dim(W) \leq \dim(V)$ will also not generally be true; consider the linear transformation which includes the line $\mathbb{R}$ into the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Knowing nothing else about the transformation other than linearity, we can't relate $\dim(V)$ and $\dim(W)$.

Comment: @Y.Forman Aha that's obvious! Wouldn't it be true for onto functions?

Comment: @Marc For onto functions, we'd have $rank(T) = \dim(W) \leq \dim(V)$ (slightly stronger than your inequality.